# Server Side Calculation using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Given the starting time/date and duration, how can I make a server side calculation that determines if an object is `"finished"`, `"in progress"`, or `"upcoming"`

```
--Show
  --duration: "144"
  --startDate: "2015-11-10"
  --startTime: "14:00"
  --status: "?"
```

Client-side javascript to determine if the show has started yet:

```
// if negative, then show hasn't started yet
var time = (-(startdate.getTime() - currentdate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60);
```

Client-side javascript to determine if the show has finished running yet:

```
// if negative, then show has finished
var timeLeft = channelDuration - timerStartTime;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I run server-side code in Firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653378/how-would-i-run-server-side-code-in-firebase)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to run your own server-side code on Firebase. See:

- [Common Firebase application architectures](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html)
- [Firebase Hosting with own server node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172320/firebase-hosting-with-own-server-node-js)
- [How would I run server-side code in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653378/how-would-i-run-server-side-code-in-firebase)
- [How to write custom code (logic) when using firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340542/how-to-write-custom-code-logic-when-using-firebase)

But you *can* store a server-side timestamp, which seems what you're trying to do:

```
ref.child('Show/startTimestamp').set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

You can then get the shows that haven't started yet with:

```
var shows = ref.child('Shows');
ref.orderByChild('startTimeStamp').startAt(Date.now()).on(...
```

Comment: Hey Frank, Any chances these features to be added in future?

Answer (score 3):

For someone passing by, I think now Firebase allow you to do this by `Cloud Function`. For this case, you can create the function that determine the `status` of the status by other parameter when the data is added to you database.

Please checkout

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/