# Push Notification with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to push notification to client app without having my own server or without using firebase panel i.e. from using firebase server.
Actually i need to send push notification on action of change in firebase data base.
Can i do custom code in firebase?

Comment: _Can i do custom code in firebase?_ Why don't you just try it? Nothing bad will happen if you try.

Comment: There is no way to [send device-to-device messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging without using a server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging). There is [no way (yet) to run your code on Firebase servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643147/server-side-calculation-using-firebase/33652773#33652773).

Comment: @bub - Fine bub. But please tell me where i put the code so that firebase can execute that code.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen - Thanks