# Firebase database change automatically

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can Firebase (or some server code) change the Firebase database automatically when an event occurred (e.g. next day)?

For example: Today's date is the 09/21/2016. When the new day begins Firebase (or the server code) should automatically move all children from "2016-09-21" to "2016-09-22".

```
"questions" : {
        "2016-09-21" : {
          "-KS2kzr30shM9l0ZEXQ0" : {
            "Level" : 2
          }
        },
        "2016-09-22" : {
          "-KS2lkuRgbT6PF9miO5c" : {
            "Level" : 1
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: Not until you are coding your own backend, which in this case NO.

Comment: While this sounds like a great feature to have, it is currently not available on Firebase without running code on a server you control. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643147/server-side-calculation-using-firebase/33652773#33652773