# Will many client-side calculations harm performance of Ionic app?

Tags: performance, google-maps, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am planning to build a location-aware app with the Ionic framework. It basically comes down to showing a Google map with the location of the user and markers in his neighbourhood. I will only show markers on the visible part of the map.

[This excellent tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/part-3-advanced-google-maps-integration-with-ionic-and-remote-data/) of Josh Morony uses a PHP script on the database. It limits the number of markers returned to the app based on a distance calculation between the user location and all markers stored in a mysql database.

However, I would like to use a Firebase database for my app. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643147/server-side-calculation-using-firebase) already points out that server-side calculations are not possible with Firebase.

Would it harm the performance of my app if I would return all markers stored in Firebase and calculate the distance on the client side? I would then limit the markers shown based on those calculations.

Or is it better to limit the number of markers returned after server-side calculations and then load the Google Map Markers?

Comment: Calculating the distance client-side and then filtering sounds like a bad idea. You're probably looking for [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/examples/README.md), which allows geo-queries on the Firebase Database.