# Firebase database, make auth uid the default id of a document

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How can I make the generated `uid` from `auth`'s `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)` be the `uid` of document?

I have this code as a signup function :

```
$scope.signup = function (user) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(ok => {
            // remove pass before saving
            delete user.password; 
            // assigning the uid
            user.uid = ok.uid;
            // saving to userRef = ...ref().child('/accounts')
            userRef.push(user)
                .then(snap => console.log(snap))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
}
```

The code above does what is expected, the output is here

[image]

So data was saved successfully but I want the value of this `-KOQOXUGH9Ahh9fukVkg` to be the value of the `uid` which is `pFNhADogjkZFz7E4osXPY48wJdS2`.

It seems that the `-KOQOXUGH9Ahh9fukVkg` is being added by `firebase` automatically. How do I control that?

Here's my `rules`

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
        "accounts": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use `set`, unique id based on timestamp will not be generated.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria it worked! Thanks! But how do I generate timestamps/

Comment: Well if you use `push`, it automatically generates timestamp based on the current time so it becomes unique but if you are talking about general timestamp in javascript then you have to use: `var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);` [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a very good JS library that is written just for dates.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria just curious why firebase isn't using isodate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
firebase.database().ref("accounts/" + ok.uid).set(user);
```

Comment: Yes I already tried that but the unnecessary id is still being generated. 

Please see this.
http://imgur.com/a/FGM1K

Comment: Are you sure you're not using 'push' at all?

Comment: Ooh I didn't see this was a `set()` sorry haha. Its working now. :)